# Why does my Gentoo installation DVD stall on the boot menu?

Tags: linux, bootloader, gentoo, intel-celeron

I am trying to boot Gentoo from a DVD on an old laptop of mine that has Windows 98 on the existing hard drive. The BIOS comes up fine, finds the bootable DVD and launches the Gentoo menu which asks what architecture I want - basically x86 or amd64. I select x86 and the process then hangs until I hard reboot.

Any ideas why this is happening? Do I need to do anything before loading the Gentoo DVD?

I am using the following iso:

> http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/x86/autobuilds/current-iso/

My system is a 500Mhz Intel Celeron with 96MB RAM.

Comment: Just use http://www.sysresccd.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disable certain options when booting the DVD, like graphical installation, usb, apic...

Check this:
http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/gentoo-x86-quickinstall.xml#doc_chap2